# Why won't my Apple USB-C to USB-C Cable Power My Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, usb

I have a wired keyboard (Drop Ctrl) plugged into a port on my Macbook Pro, and it's working.  Both the keyboard and the laptop require USB-C, so my cable is USB-C-->USB-2 with a USB2-->USB-C adapter.  (It might be USB-3 instead of 2, I'm not sure).  At any rate, the cable+adapter combo works.

I bought an Apple USB-C to USB-C cable, and it doesn't work.  The keyboard doesn't seem to get any power.

I've tried the Apple cable on all USB-C laptop ports, still doesn't work.  I went from laptop to Pixel phone using the same Apple cable and it charges the phone.  So I'm scratching my head.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that the keyboard won't work with USB-C 3, only USB-C 2.  I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I have found with macbooks.

1. my power block will stop charging my power book until I unplug it and plug it back in. It is pluggeding into a power bar so I don't see why any internal protection circuit should be tripped.
2. my childs macbook air would not power up. She was leaving it on her bed covers thus blocking the vents and overheating. Once I put it on a hard surface it started to charge and power up. It appears the system would not charge while the air vents where blocked.. I am guessing that charging causes heat and it would trip the sensor stoping charging.